# Is it possible to have multiple pointcuts with different arguments in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have single advice method with multiple pointcuts. Is it possible to have different arguments?

```
   @Around("execution(* com.admin.web.controller.*.*.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.admin.model.PortalRequestTransaction)) && args(request,portalRequestTransaction)"
        + " || execution(* com.admin.web.controller.BaselineImporterController.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,..)) && args(request)")
public Object auditAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, HttpServletRequest request,
                          PortalRequestTransaction portalRequestTransaction) throws Throwable { // some code here }
```

For example, Is it possible to the first pointcut to have 2 arguments and for the second one to have only one argument and second one passed as null?
If this is not possible, what is the best solution?

Comment: You may use [JoinPoint.getArgs()](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()) to get the method arguments as an object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using [JoinPoint.getArgs()](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()) to get the method arguments as an object array. This involves reflection.

A sample code to achieve this would be as follows

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.admin.web.controller.*.*.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.admin.model.PortalRequestTransaction))")
    public void requestNTransaction() {}
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.admin.web.controller.BaselineImporterController.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,..))")
    public void requestAsFirstArg() {}

    @Around("requestNTransaction() || requestAsFirstArg()")
    public Object auditAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        // get the signature of the method to be adviced
        System.out.println(pjp.getSignature());
        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
        for(Object arg:args) {
            // use reflection to identify and process the arguments
            System.out.println(arg.getClass());
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

}
```

Note:

1. Individual methods serving as Pointcut signature . [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts)
2. [ProceedingJoinPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) for `@Around` advice type

Comment: The answer is this point "Individual methods serving as Pointcut signature " so we can start searching for another approach. I wanted to avoid looping throw arguments by adding another @Around method and both of them calls common method with it's parameter.

Comment: This answer is correct insofar as it is a functional workaround. The actual explanation for why argument binding like this does not work is that it would be **ambiguous**: If both conditions in `||` would match, which value should be selected for binding? If you would compile this with the AspectJ compiler (not just use Spring AOP), you would see a compile error: `ambiguous binding of parameter(s) ... across '||' in pointcut`. Spring AOP uses AspectJ pointcut matching, but does not compile aspects, so you only notice during runtime that is simply does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple point-cuts in your advice, and it's done with this generic syntax:

```
@AdviceType("execution(point-cut1) || execution(point-cut2) || execution(point-cut3)")
public void foo(){}
```

Note, that `@AdviceType` and `point-cutX` are conceptual names, and you should change them respectively with your advice and pointcut[s].

Comment: Thanks Giogri, Yes I can have multiple point-cuts but i'm asking about passing different agrs, each point-cut has different args.

Comment: You want to have an optional method parameters?

Comment: Yes, for the first point-cut I want to pass 2 arguments and for the second point-cut I want to pass only one argument.

Comment: Then this is not about AOP, but rather about Java. What about defining the method with a superset of parameters and mark optional parameters as nullable? you'll just need to manually check what you have received and what not, in your method.

Comment: As it's about Java, I solved it by adding another @Around method and both of them calls common method with it's parameter.